# get raw utf8 character strings

Tags: javascript, php

I am saving a string to a data tag in html to be used by javascript and sent to a php API.  I am working with a string that looks like:

```
\n\u003\u0010\u0001\u0018
```

After I save it to the data variable, it looks like:

```
↵0
```

which is fine. The original string still appears to be intact if you do a decodeURLComponent on it.

What I'd like to do is either decode the symbols to the original string in PHP or javascript because it needs to be consumed as the original string, but I'm struggling in both spots to get it done. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Base64 to encode and decode string.

There are some example for javascript on the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding).
And PHP's documentation for [encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) and [decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php)..

Comment: How do you suggest one would accomplish this task? The following code fails, citing "Uncaught syntax error: Invalid Unicode escape sequence" - `var str = window.btoa("\n\u003\u0010\u0001\u0018");`

Comment: The string should be `var str = window.btoa("\n\u0030\u0010\u0001\u0018");`

Comment: Ahhhhh! The old "invalid data in the question" trick. Thanks.